# Two images side by side not centered

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, minipage

I have a Bode diagram composed of two graphs, I used two tikz environment instead of one, and I used minipage to put the graphs side by side. It works but the only problem is that it is not centered with the text. How can I fix that ? Do I have to work with only one tikz environment ?
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta,
                quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,matrix}                
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}


\begin{document}
\subsubsection{\underline{\textbf{$K_p > 1$} :}} on parle d'amplification, il y a un ajout de gain qui améliore la précision. D'autre part, une translation vers le haut du diagramme de la magnitude cause un élargissment de la bande passante et donc une amélioration de la rapidité.  
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\hspace{2mm}
\begin{axis}[xmode=log,xmin=1e-1,xmax=1e4,ymin=-20,ymax=20,grid=both]
%normale
\draw [blue] (axis cs:1e-1,8) ..controls (axis cs:10,8) .. (axis cs:1e4,-17);
\node at (axis cs:0.2,9) {\small \color{blue} \texttt{K=1}};
%K>1
\draw [green] (axis cs:1e-1,12) .. controls (axis cs:10,12) .. (axis cs: 1e4,-13);
\node at (axis cs:0.2,13) {\small \color{green} \texttt{K>1}};
%K<1
\draw [red] (axis cs: 1e-1,4) .. controls (axis cs:10,4) .. (axis cs: 8000, -20);
\node at (axis cs:0.2,5) {\small \color{red} \texttt{K<1}};
%0dB
\draw [thick] (axis cs:1e-1,0) -- (axis cs:1e4,0);
%omega c red
\draw [red, dashed] (axis cs:20,0) -- (axis cs:20,-20);
\node at (axis cs:13,-1) {\scriptsize \color{red} \texttt{$\omega_c$}};
%omega blue
\draw [blue, dashed] (axis cs:80,0) -- (axis cs:80,-20);
\node at (axis cs:65,-1) {\scriptsize \color{blue} \texttt{$\omega_c$}};
%omega green
\draw [green, dashed] (axis cs:260,0) -- (axis cs:260,-20);
\node at (axis cs:240,-1) {\scriptsize \color{green} \texttt{$\omega_c$}};
\end{axis}
%\fill (5.38,5.4) node[draw] {\color{gray} \texttt{Magnitude(dB)}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmode=log,xmin=1e-1,xmax=1e4,ymin=-180,ymax=-60,grid=both]
%phase
\draw [blue] (axis cs:1e-1,-70) .. controls (axis cs:50,-70) and (axis cs: 50,-180)..(axis cs:1e4,-180);
%marge Phi blue
\draw [>=stealth,blue,->] (axis cs:80,-180) -- (axis cs:80,-137);
\node at (axis cs:55,-158) {\small \color{blue} \texttt{$M_\Phi$}};
%marge Phi Red
\draw [>=stealth,red,->] (axis cs:20,-180) -- (axis cs:20,-110);
\node at (axis cs:12,-150) {\small \color{red} \texttt{$M_\Phi$}};
%marge Phi green
\draw [>=stealth,green,->] (axis cs:260,-180) -- (axis cs:260,-157);
\node at (axis cs:150,-170) {\small \color{green} \texttt{$M_\Phi$}};
\end{axis}
%phase
\fill (5.9,5.4) node[draw] {\color{gray} \texttt{Phase($^\circ$)}};
%figure
%\node at (3.5,-0.8) {\small  \texttt{fréquence angulaire (rad/s)}};
%\node at (3.5,-1.25) {\small \color{blue} \texttt{fig 12}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Diagramme de Bode du correcteur proportionnel}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your two minipages are not the same width, one is `.4\textwidth` and the other is `.5\textwidth`. Then you put `\hfill` between the two minipages `\end{minipage} \hfill \begin{minipage}`, which pushes the left minipage completely to the left and the right minipage completely to the right. It is therefore illusory to want to center in this case.

Comment: If I delete the  `\hfill` and put the same width, the problem remains the same. @AndréC

Comment: What about `.4` and `.5\textwidth` width ?

Comment: If you put each minipage in a `\fbox{}` to draw its outline, you will see that the minipages are too big. So you have to reduce their width.

Comment: I kept reducing and saw no change @AndréC

Comment: How did you manage to reduce it?

Comment: I tried `scope` for tikz environments but it doesn't work, I mean it complicates the thing. Any idea on how should I proceed ? @AndréC

Comment: With the `TikZ` option `scale=.8` by example.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you ! @AndréC

Comment: Now, answer your own question yourself as shown here : [Can I answer my own question?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I believe your diagrams would gain in quality with the `ticks=none` option. Also, your green curve might be hard to distinguish. Finally, there is no `xlabel` and `ylabel` in Bode diagrams? And your command `\subsubsection{\underline{\textbf{$K_p > 1$} :}}` is a bit questionable: `\underline` is to be avoided in general and adding command within `\subsubsection` is not welcome. You should prefer the `description` environment.

Comment: Sorry I meant `tick style={draw=none}` instead of `ticks=none`.

Comment: I have to add `style={draw=none}` on tikz options next to `scale=.8` right ? Because I tried that and saw no changes. For the labels Bode diagram does have them indeed, thank you for the reminder. And finally for the underline I will check the description environment. @pluton

Comment: no, you add `tick style={draw=none}` next to `xmode=log` in the `axis` options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @AndréC mentioned, the width of the images is too large and to change that a simple way is to use `scale=.8` in tikz option of each image.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta,
                quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,matrix}                
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}


\begin{document}
\subsubsection{\underline{\textbf{$K_p > 1$} :}} on parle d'amplification, il y a un ajout de gain qui améliore la précision. D'autre part, une translation vers le haut du diagramme de la magnitude cause un élargissment de la bande passante et donc une amélioration de la rapidité.  
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
\hspace{2mm}
\begin{axis}[xmode=log,xmin=1e-1,xmax=1e4,ymin=-20,ymax=20,grid=both]
%normale
\draw [blue] (axis cs:1e-1,8) ..controls (axis cs:10,8) .. (axis cs:1e4,-17);
\node at (axis cs:0.2,9) {\small \color{blue} \texttt{K=1}};
%K>1
\draw [green] (axis cs:1e-1,12) .. controls (axis cs:10,12) .. (axis cs: 1e4,-13);
\node at (axis cs:0.2,13) {\small \color{green} \texttt{K>1}};
%K<1
\draw [red] (axis cs: 1e-1,4) .. controls (axis cs:10,4) .. (axis cs: 8000, -20);
\node at (axis cs:0.2,5) {\small \color{red} \texttt{K<1}};
%0dB
\draw [thick] (axis cs:1e-1,0) -- (axis cs:1e4,0);
%omega c red
\draw [red, dashed] (axis cs:20,0) -- (axis cs:20,-20);
\node at (axis cs:13,-1) {\scriptsize \color{red} \texttt{$\omega_c$}};
%omega blue
\draw [blue, dashed] (axis cs:80,0) -- (axis cs:80,-20);
\node at (axis cs:65,-1) {\scriptsize \color{blue} \texttt{$\omega_c$}};
%omega green
\draw [green, dashed] (axis cs:260,0) -- (axis cs:260,-20);
\node at (axis cs:240,-1) {\scriptsize \color{green} \texttt{$\omega_c$}};
\end{axis}
%\fill (5.38,5.4) node[draw] {\color{gray} \texttt{Magnitude(dB)}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
\begin{axis}[xmode=log,xmin=1e-1,xmax=1e4,ymin=-180,ymax=-60,grid=both]
%phase
\draw [blue] (axis cs:1e-1,-70) .. controls (axis cs:50,-70) and (axis cs: 50,-180)..(axis cs:1e4,-180);
%marge Phi blue
\draw [>=stealth,blue,->] (axis cs:80,-180) -- (axis cs:80,-137);
\node at (axis cs:55,-158) {\small \color{blue} \texttt{$M_\Phi$}};
%marge Phi Red
\draw [>=stealth,red,->] (axis cs:20,-180) -- (axis cs:20,-110);
\node at (axis cs:12,-150) {\small \color{red} \texttt{$M_\Phi$}};
%marge Phi green
\draw [>=stealth,green,->] (axis cs:260,-180) -- (axis cs:260,-157);
\node at (axis cs:150,-170) {\small \color{green} \texttt{$M_\Phi$}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Diagramme de Bode du correcteur proportionnel}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Plus one for taking the trouble to answer. In 48 hours, you will be able to accept your own answer. Doing so will prevent the system from thinking that your question is unresolved, which would cause it to go up in the flow unnecessarily.

Comment: I really appreciate it.